# Delay animation when div is scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div which when I'm scrolling is floating. But inside this div I have other divs and I want those divs to come bit later than parent div.

HTML

```
<div class="left-zone col-sm-2">
    <div class="bag"></div>
    <div class="makeup"></div>
    <div class="karate"></div>
    <div class="scooter"></div>
    <div class="shoe"></div>
    <div class="armbands"></div>
    <div class="googles"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
(function($) {
    var element = $('.left-zone'),
            originalY = element.offset().top;
    var topMargin = 50;
    element.css('position', 'relative');
    $(window).on('scroll', function(event) {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        element.stop(false, false).animate({
                    top: scrollTop < originalY
                    ? 0
                    : scrollTop - originalY + topMargin
         });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: "those divs to come bit later"... explain please.

Comment: to create a delay when I scroll. So the box is coming first and then the elements inside to come after 1 second

Comment: Fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/agefz5zh/1/

Comment: This is what my code is doing. But the elements inside I want to come bit later then the parent div

Answer (score 0):

you may stop scroll with call "disableScroll" function  and re enable with "enableScroll".

```
function preventDefault(e) {
 e = e || window.event;
 if (e.preventDefault)
 e.preventDefault();
 e.returnValue = false;  
}

function disableScroll()
 window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
 window.onwheel = preventDefault; // modern standard
 window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = preventDefault; // older  browsers, IE
 window.ontouchmove  = preventDefault; // mobile
}

function enableScroll() {
 if (window.removeEventListener)
    window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
 window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = null; 
 window.onwheel = null; 
 window.ontouchmove = null; 
}
```

and change scroll with your custom animation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the SIMPLEST would be something like this:
[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h11jejdn/)

```js
var lZone = $('.left-zone');
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    lZone.css('margin-top', $(document).scrollTop() + 100);
});
```

```css
.left-zone {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 100px;
    transition: all, 0.35s;
}

div > div {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 5px;
}

.left-zone > div:first-child {background: #FF0}
.left-zone > div:nth-child(2n+3) {background: #CCC}

body {
    height: 6000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left-zone col-sm-2">
    <div class="bag"></div>
    <div class="makeup"></div>
    <div class="karate"></div>
    <div class="scooter"></div>
    <div class="shoe"></div>
    <div class="armbands"></div>
    <div class="googles"></div>
</div>
```